# how to extract longest sub string (having distinct consecutive character) from a string in java

Tags: java, string

I want to extract longest distinct consecutive substring from a string

for eg:

1 )abcdeddd
should give

abcde

2) aaabcdrrr

abcd

i wrote this code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

            String s = bf.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            TreeMap<Integer, Integer> count = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
            int point = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; j++) {
                if (s.charAt(j + 1) != s.charAt(j)) {
                    Character xyz = s.charAt(j);
                    String news = al.get(point).concat(xyz.toString());
                    al.add(point, news);

                } else if (s.charAt(j + 1) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    point++;

                }

                for (int k = 0; k < al.size(); k++) {

                    count.put(al.get(k).length(), k);

                }

                System.out.println(al.get(count.get(count.size() - 1)));

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: vote for close under minimum effort of OP

Comment: You should have told earlier that you had written some code.. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Use `LinkedHashSet`, explained here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/remove-duplicates-from-string-without-using-additional-buffer/24644#24644

Comment: How you got `abcd` from `aaabcdrrr`

Comment: abcd is the longest non repetitive substring

Comment: Why didn't you put your code first time when you ask the question?

Comment: i am new to this forum i was figuring out things. apologies

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way too.

```
    String s = "abcdefgdrrstqrstuvwxyzprr";
    Map<Integer,String> results=new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)-s.charAt(i+1)==-1){
            set.add(""+s.charAt(i));
            set.add(""+s.charAt(i+1));
        }else {
            results.put(set.size(), set.toString());
            set=new LinkedHashSet<>();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(results);
```

Out put:

```
  {0=[], 3=[r, s, t], 7=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g], 10=[q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]}
```

Now you can see all consecutive chars. and answer is largest one. In this way you can find more than one consecutive substring if they are in same length.

You can get it

```
 String largest=new ArrayList<>(results.values())
                               .get(results.size()-1).replaceAll("\\[|]|, ","");
 if("".equals(largest)){
   System.out.println("There is not consecutive substring for \""+s+"\"");
 }else {
   System.out.println("largest consecutive substring of \""+s+"\" is "+ largest);
 }
```

Now out put:

```
largest consecutive substring of "abcdefgdrrstqrstuvwxyzprr" is qrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate/check each of the character starting from character `x` where **x** is the starting point of the character checking, then increment to check if the next index of character is corresponds to the next alphabet from the last character.

**sample:**

```
String s = "abcdefgdrrstqrstuvwxyzprr";
    int start = s.charAt(0);
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    String temp2 = "";
    boolean done = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length; i++)
    {
        if(s.toCharArray()[i] == start) {
            temp.append(s.toCharArray()[i]);
            start++;
            done = true;
            if(i == s.toCharArray().length-1)
                temp2 = !(temp2.length() > temp.length()) ? temp.toString() : temp2;
        }else
        {
            if(done)
            {
                if(!(temp2.length() > temp.length()))
                    temp2 = temp.toString();
                --i;
            }
            temp = new StringBuilder("");
            done = false;
            start = (i == s.toCharArray().length-1) ? 0 : s.toCharArray()[i+1];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("LONGEST IS: " + temp2);
```

**result:**

```
qrstuvwxyz
```

And if the test String is `abcdeddd` the result would be `abcde`

Comment: Did you try with `bcdrrr`. What happen start wiht `b`? OP asked `I want to extract longest distinct consecutive substring from a string` not start with `a`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera now that is not a consecutive character, as op example start always from a.

Comment: Oh well edited to accept any starting type of consecutive characters.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it is giving correct answer for strings starting with a but for strings starting with other letter it is giving last char of string for eg:  for string "nitinj" i am getting "j" can you suggest some alteration?

Comment: @NitinJaiman actually it should not give you any.. since there is no consecutive substrings in `nitinj`. You can try this with my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
    String input = "abcdabcdeabcedeabcdefffff";

    String longest = "";
    String temp = "";

    for(int pos=0; pos<input.length(); pos++) {
        if(temp.isEmpty()) {
            temp = String.valueOf(input.charAt(pos));
        } else if(input.charAt(pos) == temp.charAt(temp.length() - 1) + 1) {
            temp += input.charAt(pos);
        } else {
            temp = String.valueOf(input.charAt(pos));
        }

        if(temp.length() > longest.length())
            longest = temp;
    }

    System.out.println(longest);
```

You could also use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for `temp` as it is more efficient for building `String`s in Java.

Comment: What about `nitinj`? It will give result as `n`.

Comment: It returns just `n`. There are only consecutive sequences of length 1 in `nitinj`. Also `i`, `t`, and `j` would be acceptable solutions from my point of view ;-)

Comment: result should be none Since there in no substring of `nitinj` having consecutive chars.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera This is just a matter of definition.